# Editing and later protecting pdf with fpdi not working

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I am having two codes one for editing already uploaded pdf and second one for securing already uploaded pfd with password

here are the code snippets

1) For pdf editing

```
require_once('fpdf.php');  
require_once('fpdi.php');  

$pdf = new FPDI();  
$filen="upload/json_tutorial.pdf";
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($filen);  

// iterate through all pages
for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
 // import a page
    $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
    $pdf->addPage();  
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx, 0, 0, 220,270);  
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 255);
    $pdf->SetXY(5, 5);
    $cur_page_no=$pdf->PageNo();
    $min=2;
    $max=10;

if((($pdf->PageNo())>=$min) && (($pdf->PageNo())<=$max))
{
    $author="AuthorName";
    $pdf->Cell(320,10,$author,0,0,'C');
}    
}

$pdf->Output('newpdf.pdf', 'D');
```

2) For Password protecting

```
function pdfEncrypt ($origFile, $password, $destFile)
{

    require_once('FPDI_Protection.php');
    $pdf =& new FPDI_Protection();
    $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($origFile);

    for ($loop = 1; $loop <= $pagecount; $loop++) 
    {
    $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($loop);
    $pdf->addPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);
    }

    $pdf->SetProtection(array(), $password,'');
    $pdf->Output($destFile, 'D');
    return $destFile;
 }
 $password = "pass123";
 $origFile = "json_tutorial.pdf";
 $destFile ="pd_protected.pdf";

 pdfEncrypt($origFile, $password, $destFile );
```

Both code works fine. But when I try to combine both of them. either of them never works as code 1 uses newer libraries and code 2 uses older. I tried to work code 2 with new libraries but gives file can not be loaded kinda errors.

I have added code 1's functionality in to code 2 like this:

```
function pdfEncrypt ($origFile, $password, $destFile)
{
    require_once('FPDI_Protection.php');
    $pdf =& new FPDI_Protection();
    $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($origFile);
    for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pagecount; $pageNo++) 
    {
    $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
    $pdf->addPage();  
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx, 0, 0, 220,270);  
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 155, 255);
    $pdf->SetXY(5, 5);
    $min=2;
    $max=10;

    if((($pdf->PageNo())>=$min) && (($pdf->PageNo())<=$max))
    {
        $author="KomalD";
        $pdf->Cell(320,10,$author,0,0,'C');
    }
    }
    $pdf->SetProtection(array(), $password,'');
    $pdf->Output($destFile, 'D');

    return $destFile;
}
$password = "pass123";
$origFile = "json_tutorial.pdf";
$destFile ="pd_protected.pdf";

pdfEncrypt($origFile, $password, $destFile );
```

This code saves the file as password protected, but does not edit it at all. neither gives any error or warning. What's I am doing wrong??

Please suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should update all used classes to their current versions:
[FPDF](http://fpdf.org/en/download.php), [FPDI](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/downloads/) and FPDI_Protection (see previous link).

After that you simply have to require the needed files and your last script should work as expected:

```
function pdfEncrypt ($origFile, $password, $destFile)
{
    require_once('fpdf.php');
    require_once('fpdi.php');
    require_once('FPDI_Protection.php');
    $pdf = new FPDI_Protection(); // <-- remove the "&"
    $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($origFile);
    ...
```